# Facing error while trying to use the English package of spacy

Tags: spacy

I need to use spacy in my program. I have installed spacy. But I am facing error while running it. Error isgiven below.
 import error: cannot import name 'en'

I tried to download en.
But the issue still not get resolved.
Please help me to resolve it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have already given answer for similar question. Anyways posting the answer for you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the below steps.

1.Open cmd using "Run as administrator"

2.Use the command

pip install -U spacy

3.To download the English package

python -m spacy download en

4.To load it

import spacy

spacy.load('en')